# Edge Loop is discontinuous, doesn't go over a face

Tags: edges

Why the edge loop won't go over a face? It ends before that face and becouse of that face, it doesn't continue over the whole model.

[image]

Comment: Edge loop will only go through quad faces. You should first link the 2 vertices at the center. Select them two and use J to join them.

Comment: Thanks! it worked:) @lemon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The edge loop stops because the next face has 6 vertices.
Edge loops ONLY travel through faces with exactly 4 vertices (aka quads).

You can connect the two vertices in the middle vertically by selecting both and pressing J. Then the loop will travel all the way through.